# Calculate a drift value from NTP

Tags: time, ntp

I have a simple NTP client that gets the value from an NTP server every 15 minutes.  All of the values are calculated as per the NTP spec to account for the delay in the request and response.

I am not correcting the system clock at this time but each time getting the offset value of the uncorrected system time to the NTP time.  I am getting values (in seconds) like on subsequent polls...

```
0.0017
0.0006
```

for offset times.

Is there a formula to calculate a drift of this particular clock at all?  In these examples all the drift calculations are +0 so the clock is running fast by a small amount but by how much?

For example say the offset was a consistent 0.9 seconds with a 15 minute NTP poll time?